# Outlook 2010 with PlayOnLinux, certificate error

Tags: wine, microsoft-office

I installed Outlook 2010 32bit on a 64bit ubuntu using PlayOnLinux. Installation ended successfully.

Since our organization uses a self-signed certificate, I had to import it in PlayOnLinux or wine to be able to conncet to my mail.

I used

```
wine /path/to/control.exe/in/playonlinux/control.exe
```

and then went to "Internet setting". There, I imported the certificate in root trusted authorities.

Despite doing all these, creating a profile on outlook will not succeed. Using wireshark, I noticed that the error returned is

> Alert (level fatal description unknown CA).

I am guessing the certificates are not imported properly.

Any suggestions?

---

Update:
I could not find what I was looking for. But to make things work temporary, I used DavMail and setup my account as an InternetMail in outlook.
I will update this post if anything new happens.

Answer (score 2):

```
wine /path/to/control.exe/in/playonlinux/control.exe
```

won't work because it will use by default `$HOME/.wine` wineprefix.

You need to type this command into PlayOnLinux's Office 2010 virtual drive.

PlayOnLinux -> Configure -> Miscellaneous -> Open a terminal

Then, type the same command, but replace wine with `POL_Wine`

Comment: Thank you. I executed control.exe using PlayOnLinux and this time I could see "Mail" icon. I also imported the certificate in "Internet Settings". Although I still get certificate error.